# Convert svg maps to jvectormap

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jvectormap

I'm using [**jvectormap**](https://github.com/manifestinteractive/jqvmap) plugin and everything works so fine but i need to add some missed country, then I searched and figured out that there was a tool to convert svg map to jvectormap js via **[svgTo](http://svgto.jvectormap.com/)** but this link not working anymore! so the question is:

> 1. Is it possible to convert svg map to jvectormap at all?
> 2. if yes, is there other tools to convert this?
> 3. if no, can i convert it manually?

based on this question [How to convert SVG to jVectorMap format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992214/how-to-convert-svg-to-jvectormap-format) or [How to generate a new, custom map for the JVectorMap jquery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571422/how-to-generate-a-new-custom-map-for-the-jvectormap-jquery-plugin?rq=1) or etc.. neihter not working for me. so we need a solution for this, thanks in advance.

@kirilllebedev

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13520307/4845566

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [link](http://svg.wangxingrong.com/) to convert SVG to jvector map.

But, this works only for older versions of Jvectormap. For latest version, I am still searching for a solution, as b-box coordinates to plot the markers based on latitude and longitudes is not working.

Comment: Have you found any solution for b-box coordinates?

Comment: Nope, I was unsuccessful.